# Dafny, call may violate context's modifies clause

Tags: verification, dafny

In my program (full version on [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Yplso)), I want to slice an array, sort each slice, and then merge them back together.

I chose to use sequences because it makes slicing and merging very easy.  Then, in order to reuse some existing code, I convert each slice to an array and call my implementation of insertion sort. But the call reports a `call may violate context's modifies clause` error. Why is that?

Here is the main portion of my code.

```
method MySort(input:array?<int>)
modifies input;
requires input != null;
requires input.Length > 0;
requires input.Length%2==0;
{
if(input.Length%2!=0){return;}
 var mid:int := input.Length/2; 
 var subOne := input[0..mid];
 var subTwo := input[mid..input.Length];
 var arrSubOne := toArrayConvert(subOne);
 var arrSubTwo := toArrayConvert(subTwo);
 insertionSort(arrSubOne); //call may violate context's modifies clause
 insertionSort(arrSubTwo); //call may violate context's modifies clause
} 

method toArrayConvert(s:seq<int>) returns(a:array<int>)
requires |s|>0;
ensures |s| == a.Length;
ensures multiset(s[..]) == multiset(old(s[..]))
ensures forall i::0<=i<a.Length ==> s[i] == a[i];
{ /* ... */ }

method insertionSort(input:array?<int>)
modifies input
requires input != null
requires input.Length > 0
ensures perm(input,old(input))
ensures sortedBetween(input, 0, input.Length) // 0 to input.Length = whole input
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that you're more likely to get exhaustive answers if you don't ask multiple questions in one post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a postcondition on `toArrayConvert`

```
ensures fresh(res)
```

Then your whole program verifies.

This postcondition guarantees that the array returned by that method is "fresh", meaning it is newly allocated. That allows Dafny to conclude that you are not modifying anything you're not supposed to: you're allowed to modify the array because you allocated it!

Please ask a separate question about the sequence swapping, or update your old question about that topic if you felt the answer was not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I could not figure it out ages :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is difficult to answer since you don't provide the contract of `insertionSort`. My guess is that `insertionSort` modifies more than it's caller, i.e. `insertionSort` lists some data in its `modifies` clauses that `MySort` doesn't list in its `modifies` clauses.

If this were allowed then a caller of `MySort` would "miss" potential modifications since, i.e. the contract of `MySort` would just be an under-approximation, which would be unsound.

Comment: really sorry there was a typo in it. the new link is https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Yplso

Comment: is it because of the local variables which are passed to method?